# Order a String column separated by Space

Tags: sql, oracle11g, toad

A table named `ASORT` has the following definition and the inserts (in specified order):

```
CREATE TABLE asort(a NUMBER, b VARCHAR2(5));

INSERT INTO asort VALUES(1, '1 11'); 
INSERT INTO asort VALUES(2, '11');
INSERT INTO asort VALUES(3, '1 10');
INSERT INTO asort VALUES(4, '1 3');
INSERT INTO asort VALUES(5, '1 5');
INSERT INTO asort VALUES(6, '1 20');
INSERT INTO asort VALUES(7, '1 14');
INSERT INTO asort VALUES(8, '1');

SELECT * 
FROM asort 
ORDER BY b; -- returns the below result
```

[image]

But the desired order is that all the numbers after the space should also be sorted like displayed below.

[image]

Please suggest a query to achieve the desired result.

Thanks..!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `regexp_substr()` to extract the nth element from the delimited list.  You can then convert these values to numbers and order by that.  Something like:

```
ORDER BY cast(replace(regexp_substr(b||' ', '[0-9]+ ', 1, 1), ' ', '') as int) NULLS FIRST,
         cast(replace(regexp_substr(b||' ', '[0-9]+ ', 1, 2), ' ', '') as int)
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/20c15/9) is a SQL Fiddle.

Comment: In the SQL Fiddle, the ordering is messed up if I remove NULLS FIRST clause from the query. Can you please help me understand the role of NULLS FIRST.

Comment: @WamglindCarmasaic . . . That just specifies where `NULL` values go.  I seemed to have missed it when I copied the query back here.